# ORA-12533: TNS:illegal ADDRESS parameters

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, tnsnames

I'm trying to open an OracleConnection on Visual Studio (c#) to join a Database with this command:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=((DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XX.XXX.X.XXX)(PORT=XXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DEPL_D)(SERVER=xxxxx0xx)));User Id=X_XXX_XXX; Password=XXXXXXXXXX");

conn.Open();
```

my tnsnames.Ora contains the connection string like this:

```
DEPL_D.WORLD=
    (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS=
                (PROTOCOL = tcp)
                (HOST = XX.XXX.X.XXX)
                (PORT = XXXX)
            )
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = DEPL_D)
            (SERVER = XXXXXXXXXX)
        )
   )
```

On the `conn.Open();` I have the message `ORA-12533: TNS: illegual ADDRESS parameter`

After having searched on the net, It seems it's a problem on my tnsnames.oRA

I have done a test SQL+ with the administrator of the database (on audio) and it works. But It doesn't with visual studio.

If anybody has any idea, everything can helps.

Thanks in advance,

Greetings,

Flo

EDIT1:

I have tried to edit the `(CONNECT_DATA =
                       (SERVICE_NAME = DEPL_D)
                       (SERVER = XXXXXXXXXX)
            )` with `(CONNECT_DATA =
                       (SID=DEPL_D)` but it doesn't works too.

Comment: Not sure this is applicable to this particular issue but, the issue I had when I got this error was that the tnsnames.ora entry was invalid, i.e. when I compared a working entry with the failing entry there appeared to be an extra character in the version that wasn't working.  I looked to see if there was a standard for formattingg.  Could not see anything mentioned here - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/tnsnames.htm#NETRF1972 (standard would be the same for most versions?).  Note that I resolved this issue by attempting to use TNSPING.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from what you've provided: The SERVICE_NAME in the connect string is not the same SERVICE_NAME from your tnsnames.ora file.

Also, why did you censor the SERVER parameter ? Only possible values are SHARED, DEDICATED or POOLED. No ip address or hostname here.

Comment: I gave the SERVER parameter because they gave me the CONNECT_DATA like this. If it's impossible to use this, I'll delete the line.

In my files it is the same, just a rewrite error. I'm not on the same computer where I code and on StackOverflow.